# Increasing the dimension of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have a subspace $T=span\{v_1,...,v_i\}$ of $R^n$ of dimension $1<i<n-1$.
If I add another vector $v_{i+1} = (0 ... 0 1)$ (all $n-1$ entries are $0$ except the last entry which is $1$, would $T' = span\{v_1,...,v_i,v_{i+1}\}$ remain a subspace of $R^n$ of dimension $i+1$?

Comment: It would be a subspace, but, it need not increase in dimension.

Comment: What kind of vector can I use in order to increase the dimension for sure?

Comment: One that is linearly independent of $v_1,\ldots,v_i$, or equivalently, one not in $T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T'$ will be a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, and $T\subseteq T'$ however, you only get an increase in dimension (and so only get $T \subset T'$) if $v_{i+1}$ is linearly independent of $v_1,\ldots,v_i$, or, equivalently, if $v_{i+1}\notin T$.

I should add, if $V$ is an arbitrary vector space and $T$ is a finite dimensional subspace, then the same thing is true in general (i.e. you increase dimension iff you add in something new, and take the span). If $T$ is infinite dimensional, then $T$ won't increase in dimension by adding in one linearly thing, and taking the span, but you will still have $T\subset T'$.